# Is it possible to make a string become a variable?

Tags: python

Is it possible to convert a string to a variable?

For example:

```
a = b = c = 0
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]

# any function or module to change my_list to below

my_list = [a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval()` for referencing variables with their names as string as follows:

```
a = b = c = 0
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]

#any function or module to change my_list to below

my_list = [eval(i) for i in my_list]
print(my_list)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 0, 0]
```